# Slow website after update to Magento 1.9.3.7

Tags: magento-1.9

I've updated Magento 1.9 to the most recent version (1.9.3.7). The category and products pages are loading just as fast as before. However, when adding a product to the cart or going through the payment process, the pages are loading really slow (~ 10 - 15 sec.).

The issues comes from a 'js.js' file. The code below is causing the slow loading times:

```
function setLocation(url){
    window.location.href = encodeURI(url);
}
```

Does anybody know why the pages are loading so slow or what I can do to fix it?